# Questions without a tag

Tags: discussion, support

I wanted to ask about a phrase I've seen used in a number of questions but I'm not sure what it means. If I post a question asking someone to define it what tags should I use? As I'm not sure what it means I don't know which tags it swould fall under!

This is was the question I posted

[What does client-side functionality mean?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53833/what-does-client-side-functionality-mean)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. are you talking about a new META post or a particular question? Have a link?

Comment: @KitMenke, actually he was wondering wich tag to use when he don't know the meaning of a term or word SharePoint related. See his question: he wasn't sure of what the expression "cliend side functionality" means in relation to SharePoint (I think he doesn't know the ecma script model, not yet ^_^). So he wasn't sure how to tag his question. There is a "Client-Object-Model" tag, but if you don't know what the client model is, you won't know if the tag fits.

Comment: @KitMenke Thats why I suggested the **Learning** tag. The question is pretty specific, so it can be usefull to other wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Learning** tag has been added to my question, this is what I was looking for